# 8 soldiers lining up for the morning assembly

Tags: mathematics, combinatorics, optimization

There are 8 soldiers, gathering and lining up every morning for their military service. The commander at the head of these soldiers demands that the morning lineup of these soldiers be arranged differently for every next day according to the following rule:

- Any three soldiers cannot be lined up next to each other in the same order for others days.

For example; If ABCDEFGH is the first arrangement for day 1, on the other days, ABC, BCD, CDE, DEF, EFG and FGH cannot be lined up next to each other in the same order any more, but ACB arrangement is okay for other days until used once since they are not in the same order.

**What is the maximum number of days can this happen?**

Comment: Was this intended to be solved by computers? Because two answers have taken a programming approach. If you don't want that then use the [no-computers] tag in the future.

Comment: @bobble both computer or no-computer is okay for me, that’s why i didnt add that tag since it may not be that easy even with computer in my opinion.

Comment: Is there more to this? I've tried playing with the generalized problem of $n$ (instead of 8) soldiers and $m$ (instead of 3) groups that can't repeat, and noticed that almost always we can find a solution that is equal to an upper bound (generalizing RobPratt's bound) except for some mysterious cases of $(n,m)$ like $(3,2),(5,2),(5,4),(7,6),...$ - *assuming my implementation is correct.*

Comment: @Vepir I didnt get into much detail for this, but probably there is a generalization possibility exists since I found my answer with some other methodology. In my methodology, two letters for the beginning and ending do not repeat itself more than 2 times. This could give you a lead, I dont know :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

An easy upper bound is

> $8\cdot 7\cdot 6 / 6 = 56$

because each day contributes $8-2=6$ triples out of $8\cdot 7 \cdot 6$.
Here's an optimal solution with

> 56 days:

> ABCEGFDH, ABEHDGCF, ADECBGHF, AEDCBHGF, AEGHCDFB, AGCBFDEH, BCDEFAHG, BDAEFGCH, BDHFECGA, BECFHGDA, BFGDEAHC, BHDCAFGE, CABGDFHE, CDBGFHAE, CEHFDAGB, CFEDGHAB, CFGHDBEA, CGDBAHEF, CGFADHEB, CHAGFEBD, CHEDBFAG, DAFBGECH, DAHFCGBE, DBHAFEGC, DFGBCAEH, DGFCHBAE, DHBFEACG, DHGAEBCF, EAFDBCHG, EBGAFCDH, EBHFGACD, EDFABHCG, EFHBGCDA, EGBACHDF, EHCFBDGA, EHGBDCFA, FAECDGBH, FBCGEHAD, FBHECAGD, FCBEGDHA, FCEAGHBD, FDCGHEAB, FHCBAGED, GADFEHBC, GAHDEBFC, GBFHDACE, GCAHBEFD, GDCEBAFH, GEADCHFB, GFBEDHCA, HACFDGEB, HCEFBADG, HEGABDFC, HFACBDEG, HGCEDABF, HGEFCADB

I used integer linear programming as follows.  For each of the $8!=40320$ permutations $p \in P$, let binary decision variable $x_p$ indicate whether that permutation appears.  For each of the $8\cdot 7\cdot 6=336$ triples $t\in T$, let $P_t \subset P$ be the subset of permutations that contain that triple. The problem is to maximize $$\sum_{p\in P} x_p \tag1$$ subject to
$$\sum_{p\in P_t} x_p \le 1 \quad \text{for $t\in T$} \tag2.$$
The objective $(1)$ maximizes the number of days, and the constraint $(2)$ enforces that each triple appears at most once.

Comment: good way to find, congratz!

Comment: If you don't mind answering, what did you use to solve this integer linear programming task and how long did it took? - I'm not familiar with linear programming, but was inspired by this to finally look into it. A google search lead me to a python modeler `PuLP` that can call `GLPK`. - But, the solving process is taking forever. I've tried setting an 1 hour time out, but the best solution it found under that time constrain was 54 days. Was this to be expected? I'd love to know what tools and tricks or references would you recommend to help improve the solving time, if you don't mind.

Comment: I used SAS.  I didn't save the log, but it took under an hour.  There can be a big performance difference between solvers.

Comment: This problem can be much harder to solve if your solver does not exploit symmetry because the branch-and-bound algorithm will then perform redundant work by processing essentially identical tree nodes.  One workaround is to fix $x_p=1$ for one permutation, say ABCDEFGH, although this still does not eliminate all symmetry.  The presolver will remove this fixed variable, any other variables that are then forced to $0$, and any constraints that then become redundant.

Comment: I switched to GUROBI academic license after GLPK did not manage to solve it over night. But, it appears that this new solver is again taking hours. I do not want to be bothering you in the comments anymore, so I'll be moving this to stack overflow. Thanks for the reply.

Comment: Another idea that might help to find 56 is to change the $\le 1$ to $=1$.

Comment: Is there another , preferably more intuitive way to solve this ? I don't know linear programming and your answer is a bit too complicated for me.

Comment: This is a *set packing* problem or “maximum independent set” problem or “node packing” problem in the graph defined in @Vepir’s answer. You could try any heuristics or exact approaches for those problems. For example, maybe try a local search that involves two moves: adding an unused node (as in the greedy heuristic) or replacing a used node with two unused nodes.

Answer (score 5):

My answer:

> 39

My method:

> I programed this python program that used brute force to find all the possible arrangements:
>
> ```
> from itertools import permutations
>
> letters = "ABCDEFGH"
> windows = len(letters) - 2
> done = list()
>
> for p in permutations(letters):
>     for i in range(windows):
>         if any("".join(p[i:i+3]) in array for array in done):
>             break
>     else:
>         print("".join(p))
>         done.append("".join(p))
> print(len(done))
> ```

Explanation of my method:

> The concept is really simple: the `letters` variable *(of type `str`)* stores all the possible positions per arrangement, the `windows` variable *(of type `int`)* stores the number of windows of 3 in a line there can be per 8 *(`len(letters)`)* positions, and the `done` variable *(of type `list`)* will store all the qualified positions.
>
> I imported the `permutations` method from the built-in `itertools` module, that will allow me to make the program iterate through and access every permutation of the `letters` string.
>
> With each permutation of `letters`, iterate through each window of three positions, and check to see if any strings in the `done` list contains the current window. If found, set break out of the loop.
>
> Only append the current permutation of `letters` if unique remains no `break` statement was met during the inner iterations, and at the end, print the number of qualified permutations found with the built-in `len()` method.

Output of my method:

> Here are all the valid arrangements of soldiers:
>
> ```
> ABCDEFGH
> ABDCEFHG
> ABECDGFH
> ABFCDHEG
> ABGCDFEH
> ABHCEDFG
> ACBDEGHF
> ACDBEHFG
> ACEBDHGF
> ACFBDGEH
> ACGBDFHE
> ACHBEFDG
> ADBCGHEF
> ADCBHFEG
> ADEBFGCH
> ADFBCEHG
> ADGBFECH
> ADHBCFGE
> AEBCHGDF
> AECBFHDG
> AEDBGFCH
> AEFBGDCH
> AEGBHDCF
> AEHBFDCG
> AFBEDGHC
> AFCBEGDH
> AFDBHECG
> AFEDHCBG
> AFHBGEDC
> AHDFCGEB
> BAFGDEHC
> BAGECFDH
> BAHCGFDE
> BDAHFCEG
> BFAGHDEC
> BHGCFEAD
> CDAGFEBH
> CHEAGDBF
> FGBCAHED
> 39
> ```

Answer (score 3):

Greedy strategy gives at most (*not optimal but close*)

> 54 days

where the greedy strategy was to

> Every day, consider only available permutations that share their triplets with the largest number of unavailable permutations. That is, every day decrease the set of available permutations by the smallest amount possible.

In other words, in terms of graph theory:

I constructed a graph $G$ whose vertices are the permutations, $|V|=8!=40320$.

Two vertices $v,w\in V$ are connected by an edge if and only if they cannot form a solution together. Then, the degree of every vertex will be $d(v)=3623$.

Let $N(v)$ denote the set of neighbors of $v\in V$ and $\overline{N}(v)=N(v)\cup\{v\}$. If we include vertex $v\in V$ in our solution, then vertices in $\overline{N}(v)$ are unusable (cannot be included in our solution).

My greedy strategy was as follows:

1. Let $X_n\subset V$ and WLOG start with any vertex $v\in V$, i.e. $X_1=\{v\}$.
2. Let $Y=\bigcup\limits_{x\in X_n} \overline{N}(x)$ and $X_{n+1}=X_{n}\cup\{z\}$ s.t. $z\in V\setminus Y$ maximizes $|N(z)\cap Y|$.

That is, at every step we pick a new vertex $z$ such that the set of unusable vertices $Y$ grows by the smallest amount possible. If there are multiple choices, we can try all of them.

There are 16 scenarios that result in solutions of 54 days, while other scenarios result in less. That is, we cannot get more than 54 days using this greedy strategy.

```
solution 54 ['01234567', '05634127', '73405126', '71205346', '03476125', '05763124', '13427605', '26305471', '46371052', '16324705', '24063571', '27160354', '52460713', '71560243', '36015724', '26045731', '67145230', '61527304', '27031546', '07624153', '46721503', '24536701', '31425706', '25370461', '36170254', '53014627', '02746531', '06147532', '54261307', '25610473', '75214306', '03647251', '51407236', '40327516', '45103726', '35172064', '31065742', '42107365', '54102673', '74013526', '74165203', '65132074', '41362507', '73562041', '41732650', '07543162', '21376540', '17564023', '50623174', '23745016', '01764235', '67504321', '02164375', '16743502']
solution 54 ['01234567', '05634127', '73405126', '71205346', '03476125', '05763124', '13427605', '26305471', '46371052', '16324705', '24063571', '27160354', '52460713', '71560243', '36015724', '26045731', '67145230', '61527304', '27031546', '07624153', '46721503', '24536701', '31425706', '25370461', '36170254', '53014627', '02746531', '06147532', '54261307', '25610473', '75214306', '03647251', '51407236', '40327516', '45103726', '35172064', '31065742', '42107365', '54102673', '74013526', '74165203', '65132074', '41362507', '73562041', '41732650', '07543162', '21376540', '17564023', '50623174', '23745016', '01764235', '67504321', '16743502', '02164375']
solution 54 ['01234567', '05634127', '73405126', '71205346', '03476125', '05763124', '13427605', '26305471', '46371052', '16324705', '24063571', '27160354', '52460713', '71560243', '36015724', '26045731', '67145230', '61527304', '27031546', '07624153', '46721503', '24536701', '31425706', '25370461', '36170254', '53014627', '02746531', '06147532', '54261307', '25610473', '75214306', '03647251', '51407236', '40327516', '45103726', '35172064', '31065742', '42107365', '54102673', '74013526', '74165203', '65132074', '41362507', '04173265', '73564201', '75620431', '06754321', '21643750', '50162374', '74350621', '31674502', '02137645', '17650423', '65402317']
solution 54 ['01234567', '05634127', '73405126', '71205346', '03476125', '05763124', '13427605', '26305471', '46371052', '16324705', '24063571', '27160354', '52460713', '71560243', '36015724', '26045731', '67145230', '61527304', '27031546', '07624153', '46721503', '24536701', '31425706', '25370461', '36170254', '53014627', '02746531', '06147532', '54261307', '25610473', '75214306', '03647251', '51407236', '40327516', '45103726', '35172064', '31065742', '42107365', '54102673', '74013526', '74165203', '65132074', '41362507', '04173265', '73564201', '75620431', '06754321', '21643750', '50162374', '74350621', '31674502', '02137645', '17650423', '64023175']
solution 54 ['01234567', '05634127', '15627340', '13427560', '25610347', '35641027', '27105346', '60327415', '52760413', '27035416', '60241735', '32471605', '46071352', '43571260', '35026714', '64023715', '74523601', '37405261', '13264705', '42635107', '47265013', '67014235', '17025364', '61370425', '32570614', '05136742', '64213057', '54203617', '07461532', '40376125', '17436520', '62503147', '14507362', '16205473', '15047623', '31750624', '53021764', '21407653', '40157632', '15246730', '47521630', '30754621', '07251463', '63751240', '72154063', '51643207', '73210465', '45731206', '30645172', '16723045', '24531067', '65437201', '20431657', '57243016']
solution 54 ['01234567', '05634127', '15627340', '13427560', '25610347', '35641027', '27105346', '60327415', '52760413', '27035416', '60241735', '32471605', '46071352', '43571260', '35026714', '64023715', '74523601', '37405261', '13264705', '42635107', '47265013', '67014235', '17025364', '61370425', '32570614', '05136742', '64213057', '54203617', '07461532', '40376125', '17436520', '62503147', '14507362', '16205473', '15047623', '31750624', '53021764', '21407653', '40157632', '15246730', '47521630', '30754621', '07251463', '63751240', '72154063', '51643207', '73210465', '45731206', '30645172', '16723045', '24531067', '65437201', '57243016', '20431657']
solution 54 ['01234567', '05634127', '15627340', '13427560', '25610347', '35641027', '27105346', '60327415', '52760413', '27035416', '60241735', '32471605', '46071352', '43571260', '35026714', '64023715', '74523601', '37405261', '13264705', '42635107', '47265013', '67014235', '17025364', '61370425', '32570614', '05136742', '64213057', '54203617', '07461532', '40376125', '17436520', '62503147', '14507362', '16205473', '15047623', '31750624', '53021764', '21407653', '40157632', '15246730', '47521630', '30754621', '07251463', '21540637', '67531240', '64375120', '65432017', '72043165', '30451672', '65172430', '57230164', '23104657', '45372106', '06457321']
solution 54 ['01234567', '05634127', '15627340', '13427560', '25610347', '35641027', '27105346', '60327415', '52760413', '27035416', '60241735', '32471605', '46071352', '43571260', '35026714', '64023715', '74523601', '37405261', '13264705', '42635107', '47265013', '67014235', '17025364', '61370425', '32570614', '05136742', '64213057', '54203617', '07461532', '40376125', '17436520', '62503147', '14507362', '16205473', '15047623', '31750624', '53021764', '21407653', '40157632', '15246730', '47521630', '30754621', '07251463', '21540637', '67531240', '64375120', '65432017', '72043165', '30451672', '65172430', '57230164', '23104657', '45372106', '20645731']
solution 54 ['01234567', '05634127', '51267340', '53467120', '61250347', '31245067', '67501342', '20367451', '16720453', '67031452', '20645731', '36475201', '42075316', '43175620', '31062754', '24063751', '74163205', '37401625', '53624701', '46231507', '47621053', '27054631', '57061324', '25370461', '36170254', '01532746', '24653017', '14603257', '07425136', '40372561', '57432160', '26103547', '54107326', '52601473', '51047263', '35710264', '13065724', '65407213', '40517236', '51642730', '47165230', '30714265', '07615423', '65140237', '27135640', '24371560', '21436057', '76043521', '30415276', '21576430', '17630524', '63504217', '41376502', '60241735']
solution 54 ['01234567', '05634127', '51267340', '53467120', '61250347', '31245067', '67501342', '20367451', '16720453', '67031452', '20645731', '36475201', '42075316', '43175620', '31062754', '24063751', '74163205', '37401625', '53624701', '46231507', '47621053', '27054631', '57061324', '25370461', '36170254', '01532746', '24653017', '14603257', '07425136', '40372561', '57432160', '26103547', '54107326', '52601473', '51047263', '35710264', '13065724', '65407213', '40517236', '51642730', '47165230', '30714265', '07615423', '65140237', '27135640', '24371560', '21436057', '76043521', '30415276', '21576430', '17630524', '63504217', '41376502', '02417365']
solution 54 ['01234567', '05634127', '51267340', '53467120', '61250347', '31245067', '67501342', '20367451', '16720453', '67031452', '20645731', '36475201', '42075316', '43175620', '31062754', '24063751', '74163205', '37401625', '53624701', '46231507', '47621053', '27054631', '57061324', '25370461', '36170254', '01532746', '24653017', '14603257', '07425136', '40372561', '57432160', '26103547', '54107326', '52601473', '51047263', '35710264', '13065724', '65407213', '40517236', '51642730', '47165230', '30714265', '07615423', '23715640', '76514023', '15243607', '73650421', '41735602', '30241576', '52763041', '64135027', '21437605', '17643052', '60435217']
solution 54 ['01234567', '05634127', '51267340', '53467120', '61250347', '31245067', '67501342', '20367451', '16720453', '67031452', '20645731', '36475201', '42075316', '43175620', '31062754', '24063751', '74163205', '37401625', '53624701', '46231507', '47621053', '27054631', '57061324', '25370461', '36170254', '01532746', '24653017', '14603257', '07425136', '40372561', '57432160', '26103547', '54107326', '52601473', '51047263', '35710264', '13065724', '65407213', '40517236', '51642730', '47165230', '30714265', '07615423', '23715640', '76514023', '15243607', '73650421', '41735602', '30241576', '52763041', '64135027', '21437605', '60435217', '17643052']
solution 54 ['01234567', '05634127', '73401562', '75601342', '03472561', '01723564', '53467201', '62301475', '42375016', '52364701', '64023175', '67520314', '16420753', '75120643', '32051764', '62041735', '27541630', '25167304', '67035142', '07264513', '42765103', '64132705', '35461702', '61370425', '32570614', '13054267', '06742135', '02547136', '14625307', '61250473', '71654302', '03247615', '15407632', '40367152', '41503762', '31576024', '35021746', '46507321', '14506273', '74053162', '74521603', '21536074', '45326107', '73126045', '45736210', '07143526', '65372140', '57124063', '10263574', '63741052', '05724631', '27104365', '52743106', '06524371']
solution 54 ['01234567', '05634127', '73401562', '75601342', '03472561', '01723564', '53467201', '62301475', '42375016', '52364701', '64023175', '67520314', '16420753', '75120643', '32051764', '62041735', '27541630', '25167304', '67035142', '07264513', '42765103', '64132705', '35461702', '61370425', '32570614', '13054267', '06742135', '02547136', '14625307', '61250473', '71654302', '03247615', '15407632', '40367152', '41503762', '31576024', '35021746', '46507321', '14506273', '74053162', '74521603', '21536074', '45326107', '73126045', '45736210', '07143526', '65372140', '57124063', '10263574', '63741052', '05724631', '27104365', '06524371', '52743106']
solution 54 ['01234567', '05634127', '73401562', '75601342', '03472561', '01723564', '53467201', '62301475', '42375016', '52364701', '64023175', '67520314', '16420753', '75120643', '32051764', '62041735', '27541630', '25167304', '67035142', '07264513', '42765103', '64132705', '35461702', '61370425', '32570614', '13054267', '06742135', '02547136', '14625307', '61250473', '71654302', '03247615', '15407632', '40367152', '41503762', '31576024', '35021746', '46507321', '14506273', '74053162', '74521603', '21536074', '45326107', '04573621', '73124605', '71260435', '02714365', '65243710', '10526374', '74310265', '35274106', '06537241', '57210463', '21406357']
solution 54 ['01234567', '05634127', '73401562', '75601342', '03472561', '01723564', '53467201', '62301475', '42375016', '52364701', '64023175', '67520314', '16420753', '75120643', '32051764', '62041735', '27541630', '25167304', '67035142', '07264513', '42765103', '64132705', '35461702', '61370425', '32570614', '13054267', '06742135', '02547136', '14625307', '61250473', '71654302', '03247615', '15407632', '40367152', '41503762', '31576024', '35021746', '46507321', '14506273', '74053162', '74521603', '21536074', '45326107', '04573621', '73124605', '71260435', '02714365', '65243710', '10526374', '74310265', '35274106', '06537241', '57210463', '24063571']
```

(*Assuming my python implementation is correct.*)

Comment: Is it possible to tweak your method and arrive at the optimal answer ?

Comment: @HemantAgarwal You could continue with this greedy solution and apply something along the lines of a local search (tabu search, ...) to try to escape the local optimum, but landing into the global optimum is not always guaranteed when using heuristic programming.